# Software supplicants for wired 802.1x besides of wpa_supplicant

Tags: networking, authentication

Is over there other supplicant library for wired ethernet 802.1X?

I know about *the* wpa_supplicant; it seems too large and heavy for my project (smallish embedded linux box with minimal resources and dependencies). Needed algorithms: MD5, later maybe PEAP, MS-CHAP. Not anything esoteric.